# JavaFX app: FXML file not found

Tags: java, javafx, java-web-start, jnlp, fxmlloader

I have my app packaged as a JAR file. Running `java -jar myapp.jar` works just fine. I want to run this app in browser, so I created the JNLP and HTML files using the `javapackage` command.

I have whitelisted my `file://` URL, enabled the console for debug output and here's what I see:

```
FXML resource = null
load fxml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2438)
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2413)
   :
```

The corresponding code is:

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            System.out.println("FXML resource = " + getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            FXMLLoader fxml_loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            Controller controller = new Controller(stage);
            fxml_loader.setController(controller);
            System.out.println("load fxml");
            Parent root = fxml_loader.load(); 
            :
```

I have verified that `Main.xml` is correctly located and properly named in the jar file (remember that running the jar file from java works).

Why isn't the `Main.fxml` file visible when running the app with webstart? (`javaws myapp.jnlp` produces the same error)

Am I missing something or is it a bug with JavaFX & JNLP?

software: Java 8 u51, Linux Centos 6 64 bit.

**Update**

I have signed my jar file, added `Permissions: sandbox` and `Codebase: *` to my manifest, added `<security><all-permissions/></security>` to my .jnlp, set the control panel settings to be as permissive as possible, whitelisted my URL (`file:/`) to no avail. My app is blocked for "security reasons". This is beyond frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your jar file is not signed?

> By default web applications run in the sandbox. To request elevated permissions, use the  tag. Note that in order for permissions to be granted, application JAR files must be signed, and the user must trust the security certificate used for signing. If the application requests elevated permissions but requirements for the user granting permissions are not met, then the application will fail to launch.
>
> Before adding code to sign your application, ensure that signing is
>   needed, because it carries a cost of overhead to perform validation
>   and often causes additional dialog boxes to be shown to the end user
>   on application startup. See Section 3.2.4, "Run in Sandbox Unless
>   Signed and Trusted" to find out when an application needs elevated
>   permissions.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABJGFB

Also check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html

Comment: Could be but the app is whitelisted, accepted, and launches without problem. Then I have this runtime error...

Comment: I assumed that if your jar was attempting to load a resource, it may require elevated permissions, even though it's inside the same jar, the method itself could require elevation.

Comment: See also: [JDK-8091203 FXML should support usage of @FXML annotation even in unsigned contexts](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091203)

Comment: Thank you jewelsa. This is useful. So it is a Java bug after all.